# Android onItemClickListener() and View errors

Tags: android

I am having some issues with the ListActivity with onItemClickListener() and View.

The error I have with the listener:
`The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)`.

The error with the View:
`View cannot be resolved to a type`.

My Code:

```
public class physActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
  {
      @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
```

And when using a quickfix on the View class, which fixes the code, it gives me this in the console:

```
[2012-02-08 15:49:53 - AH] Dx 
trouble processing "java/util/TimerTask.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-02-08 15:49:53 - AH] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-02-08 15:49:53 - AH] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

So yeah.... I'm out of ideas as to what to do with this.

Comment: Have you created (or) used anything called TimerTask class in your project?

Comment: No, What I did was let the quickfix for the View error import something, cant tell what, fixed the errors. I ran the app, and got that huge error. Im still new and dont know how to go about removing the additions the quickfix made. Cant undo due to having tried running the app... :(

Comment: The quickfix was 'Fix Project Setup'

Comment: I fixed it. It had to deal with android.jar being included in the library under project preferences twice.

Comment: Good to know. Type same thing as answer and mark it as answer. Enjoy programming.